# How can I declare this variable if it can be one of three different classes?

Tags: java, class, variables, if-statement, declaration

Ive created three classes, a SportsCar Class, MuscleCar Class and a Car Class. In my code I give the user a choice of which car class they want to create

```
if(carType.equals("A")){
    SportsCar car1 = new SportsCar(year,make);
}
else if(carType.equals("B")){
    MuscleCar car1 = new MuscleCar(year,make);
}
else if(carType.equals("C")){
    Car car1 = new Car(year,make);
}
```

I made a GUI so that the user can interact with the car but i keep on getting an error saying it cannot find the variable *car1*

```
if(choice == 0){
    car1.accelerate();
    System.out.println("Your speed: " + car1.getSpeed);
    System.out.println("Your gas level: " + car1.getGasLevel);
}
```

I know that if there was only one car class i could just declare car1 before the if statement, but it can be one of three different classes. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Did you use `extends` with your car classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a feature in Java just for that. It's called inheritance.

Basically, you can make one class a subclass of another. You use `extends` for that:

```
public class SportsCar extends Car {
```

or

```
public class MuscleCar extends Car {
```

This allows you to treat any `SportsCar` or `MuscleCar` as a `Car`. So you can declare the variable outside of the `if` statement:

```
Car car1;
```

and just assign to it from the `if` statement:

```
if(carType.equals("A")){
    car1 = new SportsCar(year,make);
} // etc.
```

The only problem is that the Java compiler will get scared that `variable car1 might not be initialized`. If `carType` is not "A",  "B", or "C", that will actually happen. So just shut it up:

```
Car car1 = null;
```

Before you do anything, please read the [Java tutorial on inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html).

Answer (score 2):

Each of those car1 variables is only visible within the scope of the if block containing it. You need to declare the car1 variable as a type which is common to all three options (I'm guessing Car) before the first if block is entered; eg

```
Car car1;

if(carType.equals("A")){
    car1 = new SportsCar(year,make);
    ...
```

Comment: It's not that the *cars* are visible, it's that the *variables* are visible within that scope...

Comment: Yeah, worded that badly didn't I.. Updated

Answer (score 1):

The `car` is improperly scoped.  I'm assuming all class other than Car you referenced are a subclass of Car.  In this case you need to move the declaration of `car` out of the if blocks, into the method or class you are attempting to use it from.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need the other cars to inherit from a base `Car` class. Then you can do `Car car1; if{...} car.accelerate()...` Otherwise, you need a "default" clause in the if statement so that no matter what, car1 gets initialized.